# HTML5 / CSS input field with image as submit-button inside the input field

Tags: css, image, input

I tried to get an input field with an submit-button inside it. Instead of using the "normal" submit button, I tried to insert a small icon into the input-field, but without any success. I wasn't able to get the image (dimensions 30*30 pixels) inside my input-field.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            input[type=text] {
                position: relative;
                width: 200px;
                height: 36px;
                box-sizing: border-box;
                border: 2px solid #4d7fc3;
                border-radius: 4px;
                font-size: 16px;
                background-color: white;
                padding: 2px 2px 2px 10px;
            }
            input[type=submit] {
                position: absolute
                width: 30px;
                height: 30px;
                top: 0px;
                right: 0px;
                /* background-color: #4d7fc3; */
                   border: none;
                   color: white;
                   background-image: url('file:///C|/Users/heilemann/Pictures/LoginPfeil.JPG');
                   display: block;
                   background-position: 100px 100px 100px 100px; */
                /* background-repeat: no-repeat; */
                /* padding: 2px 2px 2px 30px; */
                    z-index: -1;
                margin: 10px;
                cursor: pointer;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>Input with icon:</p>
        <form>
            <div id="Search">
                  <input type="text" name="search" placeholder="Search..">
                  <input type="submit" value="">
            </div>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

It should look like this:

[image]

Comment: Try reducing the code we need to look at. Also, your image's link isn't showing up.

Comment: Why not use `<input type="image">`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were quite a few errors in the code you pasted up above which weren't doing you any favors.

You left out a `;` after the `position: absolute;` property in your `submit` input.  In order to then have that element positioned properly, you need the parent container to be `position: relative;`.  In this case, the parent container was `#Search`.

Once that was taken care of there was quite a few properties that could be removed due to being unnecessary.  See if my code below helps...

```
#Search {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

input[type=text] {
  position: relative;
    width: 200px;
    height: 36px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 2px solid #4d7fc3;
  border-radius: 4px;
  font-size: 16px;
  background-color: white;
  /* 40px padding to account for submit   */
  padding: 2px 40px 2px 10px; 
}
input[type=submit] {
  position:absolute;
  width: 30px;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  background: url('file:///C|/Users/heilemann/Pictures/LoginPfeil.JPG') #4d7fc3 center center no-repeat;
  display: block;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

[Working codepen here.](http://codepen.io/ekfuhrmann/pen/KgpmKy?editors=1100)

Just a heads up that your background image for the `submit` is referencing a local file on **your** machine, so no one else can actually see it other than you.  Be sure to assign it the correct path in relation from the index.html file.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Here it is done with HTML and CSS.

```css
/*Clearing Floats*/
.cf:before, .cf:after{
    content: "";
    display: table;
}

.cf:after{
    clear: both;
}

.cf{
    zoom: 1;
}
/* Form wrapper styling */
.form-wrapper {
    width: 450px;
    padding: 15px;
    margin: 150px auto 50px auto;
    background: #444;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
    border-radius: 10px;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .4) inset, 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, .2);
}

/* Form text input */

.form-wrapper input {
    width: 330px;
    height: 20px;
    padding: 10px 5px;
    float: left;
    font: bold 15px 'lucida sans', 'trebuchet MS', 'Tahoma';
    border: 0;
    background: #eee;
    border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}

.form-wrapper input:focus {
    outline: 0;
    background: #fff;
    box-shadow: 0 0 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .8) inset;
}

.form-wrapper input::-webkit-input-placeholder {
   color: #999;
   font-weight: normal;
   font-style: italic;
}

.form-wrapper input:-moz-placeholder {
    color: #999;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: italic;
}

.form-wrapper input:-ms-input-placeholder {
    color: #999;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: italic;
}

/* Form submit button */
.form-wrapper button {
    overflow: visible;
    position: relative;
    float: right;
    border: 0;
    padding: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
    height: 40px;
    width: 110px;
    font: bold 15px/40px 'lucida sans', 'trebuchet MS', 'Tahoma';
    color: #fff;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    background: #d83c3c;
    border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
    text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
}

.form-wrapper button:hover{
    background: #e54040;
}

.form-wrapper button:active,
.form-wrapper button:focus{
    background: #c42f2f;
    outline: 0;
}

.form-wrapper button:before { /* Left arrow */
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    border-width: 8px 8px 8px 0;
    border-style: solid solid solid none;
    border-color: transparent #d83c3c transparent;
    top: 12px;
    left: -6px;
}

.form-wrapper button:hover:before{
    border-right-color: #e54040;
}

.form-wrapper button:focus:before,
.form-wrapper button:active:before{
        border-right-color: #c42f2f;
}

.form-wrapper button::-moz-focus-inner { /* Remove extra button spacing for Mozilla Firefox */
    border: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<form class="form-wrapper cf">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Search..." required>
    <button type="submit">Search</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

tried both variants, both variants will work, second solution comes clothest